# How to implement Evenkit in order to request permission

Tags: swift, macos

I'm building a mac application which should add a reminder in calendar. The build goes without errors nor warning but when the app launch, I get the following error : 
"Reminder failed with error Access to this event store is unauthorized."

I have search the web for the right way to request access to calendar on the mac but have not found any.

I have try to translate the following exemple from ios to mac but it failed: https://github.com/andrewcbancroft/EventTracker/tree/ask-for-permission

Here is my code :

```
import Cocoa
import EventKit
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    var eventStore = EKEventStore()
    var calendars: [EKCalendar]?
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)
        reminder.title = "Go to the store and buy milk"
        reminder.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
        do
        {
            try eventStore.save(reminder,
                                commit: true)
        } catch let error {
            print("Reminder failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: `EvenKit`?  What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call [`requestAccess(to:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507547-requestaccess) on the event store for example

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder) { (granted, error) in
    if let error = error {
       print(error)
       return
    }
    if granted {
       // go on managing reminders
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for this quick and right answer to my question. Long live Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
import Cocoa
import EventKit

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    var eventStore = EKEventStore()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder)
        { (granted, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            if granted
            {
                let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)
                reminder.title = "Go to the store and buy milk"
                reminder.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
                let date : NSDate = NSDate()
                let alarm : EKAlarm = EKAlarm (absoluteDate: date.addingTimeInterval(10) as Date)
                reminder.addAlarm(alarm)
                do
                {
                    try self.eventStore.save(reminder,commit: true)
                }
                catch let error {print("Reminder failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")}
            }
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```